# The font size in my page

Tags: fontsize

In my report the chapter 1 have a small text but the chapter 2 have a big text !
someone now what the probleme !? I hope I explain well my problem

this the code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{extreport} %document A4 type rapport

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % les caractère spéciaux

\usepackage[french]{babel}  %traduire les mots anglais en français.

\usepackage{graphicx} %Package pour les images.

\usepackage{geometry} % la margine de la page

\usepackage{fancyheadings}% l'entête et le pied de page

% paramètre de l'entête du page et pied du page

\lhead{\leftmark}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage}

\cfoot{}

\pagestyle{fancy}

 \usepackage{float}

%Pour l'index



\usepackage{listings} % encadrer les codes sources

\usepackage{color} 

\usepackage{setspace} %espace entre paragraphe

\usepackage{enumitem} %package de liste

\usepackage{xcolor} %package de liste

%\onehalfspacing %espace 1.5 cm
% \doublespace %espace double
% ***** on peut l'utiliser comme une environnement ******/



% \definecolor{name}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5} %définir une couleur pour l'encadrement du code source ( ici graylight)
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}


\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Codes}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Liste des \lstlistingname }


%\geometry{hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=2cm}

\geometry{top=5cm, bottom=5cm,left=4cm, right=4cm}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty} %enlever la numéro du premier page ( page courant )
\begin{centering}

\Large{xxx } \\
\huge{\textbf{FACULTÉ DES SCIENCES} } \\

\hspace{3.5cm} %pour insérer un espace horizontal dans un texte. ---  \hspace* force l'insertion d'un espace même en début ou en fin de ligne. -----

\includegraphics[width=30mm]{fsr.jpg} \\

\vspace*{3cm}

\large{DÉPARTEMENT D'INFORMATIQUE} \\

\hspace{3cm}

\large{FILIÈRE} \\
\large{LICENCE PROFESSIONNELLE} \\
\large{xx} \\
\large{PROMOTION 2013-2014} \\

\vspace*{1cm}

\fcolorbox{black}{lightgray}{
\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\vspace*{0.2cm}
  \centering{ \Large{\textbf{MÉMOIRE DE FIN D'ÉTUDE} }} 
\vspace*{0.2cm}
\end{minipage}
}

\vspace*{1cm}

\Large{Intitulé}\\

\Large{\textbf{xxx}} \\

\vspace*{1cm}

\Large{Présenté par :} \\

\end{centering}



% ************************************************************************************************** %
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\listoffigures

\newpage
\lstlistoflistings


\newpage
\vspace*{1cm}
\textbf{ \Huge{Remerciement}}\\

\begin{onehalfspacing}

L’achèvement de ce modeste travail n’a pas pu être réalisé sans la présence et  l’intervention généreuse de nos professeurs
, c’est le fruit de leurs  conseils précieux et de leurs efforts respectueux. A cet effet, nous tenons à présenter nos remerciements les plus sincères et nos respects les plus distingués à tous ceux qui nous ont assisté durant la réalisation de ce projet, en particulier notre encadrant \textit{xxxl} , ainsi nos Professeurs. Nous garderons toujours d’eux un très bon souvenir de leurs disponibilités et de leur enseignement riche, clair et méthodique. Que tous ceux qui nous ont aidés, de près ou de loin, trouvent ici l’expression de nos sentiments les meilleurs. Mentionnons aussi que l’aide et l’encouragement que nous a donné nos familles et nos 
proches ont beaucoup compté dans la réalisation de ce projet.
\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{onehalfspacing}

\chapter{Introduction} % Chapitre 1
\parindent=1cm
\begin{onehalfspacing}

La réalisation d'un projet de fin d'étude est une occasion pour l'étudiant d'évaluer ses connaissances, c'est une expérience nécessaire qui permet lors des dernières années d'études de découvrir la difficulté d'appliquer les notions théorique acquises lors de la formation dans un travail purement pratique.

\end{onehalfspacing}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter{Chapitre 2} % Chapitre 2

On sait depuis longtemps que travailler avec du texte lisible et contenant du sens est source de distractions, et empêche de se concentrer sur la mise en page elle-même.
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include an example code that reproduces the problem. Without this it will be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: Somewhere you are changing the font size. Without a MWE is hard to tell exactly where the culprit is. Please add to your question a MWE.

Comment: You have an error somewhere, probably a missing `}` hard to say as you give no information. Does the log report any error?

Comment: You probably have issued a font size changing command in the wrong way: it's `{\large <text>\par}` (the `\par` is not always needed), not `\large{<text>}`

Comment: I edit my question :)

Comment: when i compile your code on my machine everything seems fine so i'm  not quite sure what you mean! why do you set `\begin{onehalfspacing}` and `\end{onehalfspacing}` around the text in the introduction but not in chapter 2? i dont think you have to do that

Comment: Indeed, the font sizes appear the same to me as well. However, I notice that you are using `\large` incorrectly, as predicted by @egreg, so you should correct this in your original document.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have issued a font size changing command in the wrong way: it's

```
{\large <text>\par}
```

(the `\par` is not always needed), not

```
\large{<text>}
```

Font size changing commands do not take an argument, but are *declarations* that are in force for the whole group or environment they appear in or another declaration of the same kind countermands it. A `\par` (or `\\` in a `center` environment) should be issued when the text forms one or more lines by itself.

A better code for your title page is

```
\begin{center} % not centering

\Large xxx \\
\huge\bfseries FACULTÉ DES SCIENCES\\

\includegraphics[width=30mm]{fsr.jpg} \\[3cm]

\large DÉPARTEMENT D'INFORMATIQUE \\

\large FILIÈRE \\
LICENCE PROFESSIONNELLE \\
xx \\
PROMOTION 2013-2014 \\[1cm]

\fcolorbox{black}{lightgray}{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}
\vspace*{0.2cm}

\centering\Large\bfseries MÉMOIRE DE FIN D'ÉTUDE

\vspace*{0.2cm}
\end{minipage}%
} \\[1cm]

\Large Intitulé

\textbf{xxx} \\[1cm]

Présenté par : \\

\end{center}
```